# Unexplained Packets being dropped

Tags: windows, nic, latency

I have two servers one sending large amounts of data to the other, we are noticing that one server is sending data to the other but the receiving server is missing some of the data or packets. I am currently comparing nic's they are setup as follows:

Server 1 (sender) "NC542m Dual Port Flex-10 10GbE BL-c Adapter (Mcast)"

Flow Control - Disabled

Forward send packets to a different - enabled

header data split - disabled

Interrupt moderation - disabled

Interrupt moderation TX packet Con.. - 0

Interrupt moderation TX packet Tim.. - 0

IPV4 Checksum Offload - Tx & Rx Enabled

Large send offload - Enabled

Max fram size - 1500

Number of polls on Rec - 10000

Polling moderation TX packet cou - 1

Polling moderation TX packet time - 1

Priority & Vlan Tag - Priority & Vlan Disabled

Recieve Completion method - Adaptive

Receive ring size - 2048

Receive side scaling - Disabled

Rx interrupt moderation type - Static

Send completion Method - Polling

Send ring size - 4096

TCP/UDP IPV4 - checksum offload - Tx & RX enabled

TCP/UDP IPV6 - checksum offload - Tx & RX enabled

Transmit control blocks - 16

Use rss ti direct udp traffic - disabled

...rest are disabled.

Server 2 "NC542m Dual Port Flex-10 10GbE BL-c (Mcast)

Flow Control - Tx & Rx Enabled

Interrupt moderation - Enabled

Interrupt moderation TX packet Con.. - 0

Interrupt moderation TX packet Tim.. - 0

IPV4 Checksum Offload - Tx & Rx Enabled

Large send offload - Enabled

Max fram size - 1500

Number of polls on Rec - 10000

Polling moderation TX packet cou - 1

Polling moderation TX packet time - 20

Priority & Vlan Tag - Priority & Vlan enabled

Recieve Completion method - Adaptive

Receive ring size - 1024

Receive side scaling - enabled

Rx interrupt moderation type - adaptive

Send completion Method - interrupts

Send ring size - 2048

TCP/UDP IPV4 - checksum offload - Tx & RX enabled

TCP/UDP IPV6 - checksum offload - disabled

Transmit control blocks - 16

Use rss ti direct udp traffic - disabled

Should these cards mirror each others settings, also what would be the optimal settings for the NC542m?

Comment: I would suspect it to be more of a switch/router issue rather than a NIC issue.  What kind of networking gear are you passing through.  If its cisco, use 'clear logging' and 'show logging' to watch for dropped packets there.

Comment: How are you determining that the receiver is missing data?

Comment: NIC settings can be changed completely independently, especially as one is mainly receiving and the other mainly sending, but settings might need fine-tuning depending on the answer to the following questions. But we need more info to help. 1. What protocol - TCP? UDP? ... 2. How many packets per sec? 10kpps? 100kpps? 1Mpps? 3. Physical machines? Virtual machines? 4. What hardware, e.g. how many cores, on how many NUMA nodes?